# How to save token in localStorage safely

Tags: javascript, local-storage, xss, access-token, refresh-token

I'm looking for recommendations regarding the process of storing a refresh token in localStorage for Single Page Web Applications.

Currently I have a web application and I want to implement a process for authenticate the user based on refresh tokens.

Here's a brief description of what I want to do:

User performs a login.

After successful login, I generate an access token with expiration set to 24 hours and a refresh token with expiration set to 6 months.

Both tokens are stored in localStorage.

I am using a library for my web application, and in the documentation of that library I got this warning in case you want to save tokens in localStorage:

*Storing tokens in browser local storage provides persistence across page refreshes and browser tabs. However, if an attacker can achieve running JavaScript in the SPA using a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack, they can retrieve the tokens stored in local storage. A vulnerability leading to a successful XSS attack can be either in the SPA source code or in any third-party JavaScript code (such as bootstrap, jQuery, or Google Analytics) included in the SPA.*

I read about this and found a lot of articles from Auth0, Okta, OWASP recommending to avoid storing tokens or any sensitive data in local or session storage.

I don't really know the impact of the process I previously described when talking about XSS attacks.

I understand that the tokens saved to localStorage can be retrieved by an attacker using XSS.

However I am also using token rotation feature.

Token rotation can detect if Refresh token is being reused and as a consequence the library I am using for authentication will invalidate the token for both the attacker and the legitimate user forcing to re-authenticate.

Could this feature keep my application safe against this attacks? Let's analyze the following scenario:

Bob log into my web application https://mywebapp.com

In Bob's browser localStorage, there are two tokens AT1 and RT1.

Bob then closes the browser and returns the next day.

As AT1 already expired, web application uses RT1 to get a new Access Token.

Due to rotation, after a new pair AT2 and RT2 is provided and saved to localStorage, RT1 (even when it last for 6 months) is invalidated and cannot be used again.

An attacker executes an XSS attack and is able to retrieve the localStorage information from Bob.

At this moment the attacker has RT2 and AT2.

When attacker tries to get a new token due to AT2 expired, my application (using the library for authentication) identifies a token re-use case and automatically invalidates RT2 without generating a new token so attacker lost both tokens.

Bob now tries to access my web application using RT2 because thats the token he has in localStorage. As RT2 was invalidated, my web application will force Bob to re authenticate.

Any advice or recommendation is appreciated.

I am still a beginner in cybersecurity so even when in my opinion this implementation will work without any major concerns, I want to listen the opinions of the cybersecurity community.

What do you think about this?

Thanks.

Comment: This is what HttpOnly cookies are for. Is there a specific reason you need it to be in localStorage instead?

Comment: @AndrewParks the token is served by the library I mentioned directly to frontend. Only backend can set a cookie to be HttpOnly, that's why HttpOnly is not an option. Also, the only valid places to save the token for our library are memory cache or local storage.

Comment: Why is it that the backend is not the one that is delivering the token to you? Is the problem that the backend that sends you the token is on a different server? If you want the client to have a secret that can't be extracted, then the proper way to do this would be to create a non-extractable asymmetric key pair on the client (your browser will generate the pair but not let you see the private key). Then you would provide signatures demonstrating you have the private key See [generateKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/generateKey)